# Errors when running TensorFlow object detection API model training

Tags: python, tensorflow, macos-sierra, object-detection

I was following the instruction of *TensorFlow Object Detection API*, and I was trying to train a model with Oxford cats data set, I did every step on the instruction but the training process didn't start and gives some errors, anyone who has similar error could share experience with me?

My system is macOS Sierra 10.12.4, Python version 2.7.13

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 197, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 144, in main
    model_config, train_config, input_config = get_configs_from_multiple_files()
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 126, in get_configs_from_multiple_files
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), train_config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
    pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: .
```

The command I ran in the console:

```
python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipline_config_path=object_detection/models/pet_model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --train_dir=object_detection/models/pet_model/train
```

Answer (score 1):

update

Just find the answer to this issue, it caused by a typo. The command should be

```
python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=object_detection/models/pet_model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --train_dir=object_detection/models/pet_model/train
```